# Determine where env variable is set

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

At some point when I first started programming and had no idea what I was doing, I installed python 2 in some idiotic way. My python `env` currently points to `python2.7`, but for the life of me I cannot find where this is set. I checked my `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, and the similar files. Also when I type `env` it is not listed as one of the `env` variables. How can I determine where my `python` `env` variable is set? I'd like it to point to `python3` not `python2`

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Run `which python2.7`... Also almost all Linux or Mac come with Python 2 pre-installed

Comment: `python` is almost certainly not an environment variable itself. Rather you should be looking in your `PATH` variable for the directories where executables are searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a symlink in `/usr/bin` that's getting resolved to python2

> I'd like it to point to python3 not python2

Then edit one of those bashrc or profile files yourself such that  Python3 is on the PATH before everything else

Personally, I use [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)  rather than trusting the OS package installers

Comment: On most platforms, you should not muck with `/usr/bin` directly. If you are on Debian, the system `python` always refers to Python 2, and breaking that policy will have unpleasant consequences.

Comment: I wasn't saying to edit that, I was answering that's where the executable could exist within the env

Comment: Yup; just emphasizing that some ideas that could come up from reading this are particularly bad.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Python 2 and 3 installed, a simple and safe workaround is to just specify the version explicitly like this:

```
python2 yourProgram.py
python3 yourProgram.py
```

Assuming you're using Linux, you could even create an alias:

```
alias python=python3
```

That way you can just type

```
python yourProgram.py
```

Changing the symlink in /usr/bin is not recommended because there might be system programs using Python 2 which could then potentially break.